# What do Connie's two navels represent?

Tags: short-stories, symbolism, nick-joaquin

Nick Joaquin's story "The Woman Who Had Two Navels" opens with the following words:

> When she told him she had two navels he believed her at once: (...)

"She" is Connie de Vidal, who tells Pepe Monson that her mother and the maids had always pretended not to see that she had two navels and that she had always hidden her secret from other people. We never find out whether Connie really has two navels and her mother denies the claim. Nevertheless, the two navels are part of the story's title, so they must have meaning beyond the literal level. What do Connie's two navels actually represent or symbolise?

Comment: [This article](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/j.1467-971X.1990.tb00260.x) contains a number of interpretations of the significance of the two navels. I could try to turn this into an answer, but I haven't read the book so I'd have to do some copy-pasting and wouldn't be able to supplement the article's conclusions with my own analysis. Would you like me to do that, or would you rather write a self-answer based on this source?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Thanks for the reference. I've been thinking about self-answering the question based on my own reading and a few other texts I found online.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>This answer is largely based on the article [Fernando Zialcita, "Nick  Joaquin:  a  portrait  of  the  existentialist  as Filipino", *World Englishes* 9(2) (1990), pp.  215-223](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/j.1467-971X.1990.tb00260.x). I haven't read "The Woman who had Two Navels" myself.</sup>

Firstly, there is an external or "out of universe" perspective of what the two navels can be seen as symbolising in Joaquin's story. This is explored by Josefina D. Constantino in a book chapter "Illusion and Reality in Nick Joaquin", pp. 13-14 in [Joseph A. Galdon, ed., *Philippine Fiction*, Ateneo de Manila University Press, Quezon City, 1972](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Philippine-fiction-Essays-Studies-1953-1972/dp/B0014M838E). The following summary is quoted from the Zialcita article, as I haven't been able to access the Constantino chapter directly:

> the  two  navels  as  symbolic of  several things:
>
> 1. Life’s  two  universes,  illusion  and  fact,
> 2. of  evil  and good,
> 3. of Connie’s two existences: her childhood world of supposed innocence and her adult world of  confusion and eventual  regeneration.

On the other hand, a [phenomenological](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/phenomenology/) approach, from Connie's own perspective, offers (according to Zialcita) an alternative three interpretations of the two navels:

1. > Connie grew up during the  1930s when Manila still had an annual carnival. The merry-making  had, as an   emblem  of  luck,  a  Chinese deity,  Biliken,  who  had  a perpetual grin, long ears, and a  fat, naked  belly.  Since her  father, Manolo, was  a carnival  director  she insisted on having a  copy of  the idol  made for their  garden.  There she spent afternoons sharing tea and cookies with her  toy.  Returning  to her  ancestral home after the war,  she finds  the  place  in  ruins  and  her  Biliken  on its  back,  with  two  bullet  holes  through  the
   > belly.
   > Biliken  thus  suggests  a  childhood,  an innocence  and peace  which  she,  in  her  current  distress,  wants  to  regain.  Indeed,  a  week  after she discovers  the  letters,  on the day she cracks up, she finds herself driving back  to Biliken in what is the begining of  a new  habit.
2. > The two navels also symbolize her  lack  of  personal  autonomy.  She dreams that she is her  mother  but  also still herself.  *“I   didn’t  know  which one I  really  was.  I had  somehow become  both  of  us”*  (Joaquin, ca  1972:  95). And when  she is  woken up by  her  husband moving  beside  her,  she  suddenly  believes  that the two  navels  were  there.
3. > Bewildered  about her  sources and  her  goals in  life,  Connie  sees her  body’s  center  as not  one but  two. Connie’s portrait  is  that of  a schizophrenic. The boundaries of  her  self-experience  are vague and indeterminate. At one moment, she identifies  herself  with Biliken;  her trauma has caused such severe distress that she finds herself  drawn in two directions-on the one hand, she wants to   be rid  of her obsession (she asks Pepe for an operation); on the other, she clings to the obsession, for this allows her to   withdraw from life by refusing to choose: *"You see, I  had made up my  mind to be bad,  to be wicked.  But  now  I  had been marked out, cut off   from
   > everybody,  like  a  leper.  I had  been  saved  from  myself"*  (Joaquin, ca  1972: 95).

So there's many possible things that the two navels could represent: nostalgia for the idol Biliken (with its two belly holes like her two navels), Connie's lack of autonomy from her mother (the navel, in any human, represents one's tie to one's mother), and her schizophrenia (two body centre points instead of one).